# Get letter by position

Tags: go

I read the article https://blog.golang.org/strings and realized that you can only determine the letter by position number using package "unicode/utf8" (maybe I'm wrong). I looked at all the functions of the package, but I did not understand how to do it?
I need (pseudocode):

```
var word := "golang"
var letter := word[3] // letter a
```

Comment: @icza It seems, but no. He says how to print all the characters and their positions, I do not understand how to enter a position and get a symbol.

Comment: Based on the other answer you have all position-symbol pairs.  You can't choose a specific pair from this given the position?

Comment: @icza Can I do this task without a loop?

Comment: You can, if  you convert it to a `[]rune` first and index that. But a `for` loop is more efficient.

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate.